# How to make loop in gallery jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have plain jQuery-gallery with popup. And stuck on making loop. I think that after reaching last image have to back to the first, but how?
https://codepen.io/Slava91/pen/pwBrLP?editors=0000

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#thumbnail li a").click(function(){
    $('#thumbnail a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass(' active');

        $("#large img").attr({
      "src": $(this).attr("href"), 
      "title": $("> img", this).attr("title")});

    $("#large h2").html($("> img", this).attr("title"));
        return false;
    });

    //close button//
    $('.close').click(function(){
        $('.modal-window').css('display', 'none');
    })

  //popup window after click on big img//
    $('#large img').click(function(){

        $('.modal-window').css('display', 'block');
        $('.modal-content').attr({
      'src':$(this).attr('src')})
    })

  //navigation in popup window//
    $('.next').on('click', (function(){

        var currentActive = $('a.active').removeClass('active')
                          .parent().next().find('a').addClass('active');

    $('.modal-content').attr('src', currentActive.attr('href'));
    }))

  $('.prev').click(function(){
    var currentActive2 = $('a.active').removeClass('active')
                          .parent().prev().find('a').addClass('active');

    $('.modal-content').attr('src', currentActive2.attr('href'));
  })

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that after reaching last image have to back to the first, but how?

This problem is valid for the next and previous (go to the first or to the last...).

A way to solve this is to test if you are on the last/first slide and so you can get the first/last according to the button (next/prev):

For details you may see the next and prev click handlers in the following snippet:

```js
$("#thumbnail li a").click(function () {
    $('#thumbnail a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass(' active');

    $("#large img").attr({
        "src": $(this).attr("href"),
        "title": $("> img", this).attr("title")
    });

    $("#large h2").html($("> img", this).attr("title"));
    return false;
});

//close button//
$('.close').click(function () {
    $('.modal-window').css('display', 'none');
})

//popup window after click on big img//
$('#large img').click(function () {

    $('.modal-window').css('display', 'block');
    $('.modal-content').attr({
        'src': $(this).attr('src')
    })
})

//navigation in popup window//
$('.next').on('click', (function () {
    var currentActive = this;
    if ($('a.active').parent().next().length == 0) {
        // if last get first...
        currentActive = $('a.active').removeClass('active')
                .closest('ul').find('li:first a').addClass('active');
    } else {
        currentActive = $('a.active').removeClass('active')
                .parent().next().find('a').addClass('active');
    }

    $('.modal-content').attr('src', currentActive.attr('href'));
}))

$('.prev').click(function () {
    var currentActive = this;
    if ($('a.active').parent().prev().length == 0) {
        // if first get last...
        currentActive = $('a.active').removeClass('active')
                .closest('ul').find('li:last a').addClass('active');
    } else {
        currentActive = $('a.active').removeClass('active')
                .parent().prev().find('a').addClass('active');
    }

    $('.modal-content').attr('src', currentActive.attr('href'));
})
```

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
}

#large {
    width: 600px;
    /* height: 350px; */
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#large img {
    width: 600px;
    /* height: 263px; */
    border: 5px solid #223348;
}

#thumbnail {
    width: 210px;
    height: 256px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #223348;
    background: #fff;
}

#thumbnail li {
    float: left;
    width: 79px;
    margin: 8px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#thumbnail a {
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 56px;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#thumbnail a:hover {
    border-color: #405061;
}

.modal-window {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);

}

.modal-content {
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: auto;

    display: block;
}

.caption {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
    display: block;
}

.modal-content, .caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: .6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {
        transform: scale(0)
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1)
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1)
    }
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: .3s;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #bbb;
}

.paganation {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    right: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="large">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=1" title="" alt="image01.jpg" />
</div>

<ul id="thumbnail">

    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=1" class="active"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=1" title="" alt="image01.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=2" title="" alt="image02.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=3"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=3" title="" alt="image03.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=4"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=4" title="" alt="image04.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=5"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=5" title="" alt="image05.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=6"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=6" title="" alt="image06.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=7"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=7" title="" alt="image07.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=8"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=8" title="" alt="image08.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=9"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=9" title="" alt="image09.jpg" /></a></li>

</ul>

<div class="modal-window">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content">
    <div class="caption"></div>
    <div class="paganation">
        <span class="prev">&#10094;</span>
        <span class="next">&#10095;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```